# I cannot delete div element using filter() in React

Tags: reactjs

I was able to add div element  with delete button. I want to delete each div element when I click the delete button.
How can I achieve this, I used the filter method but still missing something

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";

function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("")
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([])

  function createTodo(){
    if(todos.find(todo => todo["name"] === task)){
      setErrorMessage(`${task} already exists`)
      return true;
    }
    else {
      setTodos(oldTodos => {
        return [...oldTodos, {"name":task, "id": oldTodos.length}] 
      })
      setTask(""); 
      return false;
    }
         
      //console.log(`Task Value: ${task}`)
  }

  //delete task
  function deleteTask(taskID){
      setTodos(oldTodos =>  oldTodos.filter(todo => todo !==taskID))
      //console.log(taskID);
  }
  return (
      <div>
      <h1>This is the Best ToDO app Ever</h1>
      <input type="text" value={task} onChange={event => {setTask(event.target.value)
      }}
      onKeyPress={(ev) => {
        if (ev.key === "Enter") {
          ev.preventDefault();
          createTodo();
        }
      }}
      />
       <button onClick={createTodo}> Create Todo </button>
        
        <ul>
            {todos.map(todo => {
                return  <div key={`${todo["name"]}-${todo["id"]}`}>
                  <li>{todo["name"]}</li>
                <button onClick={() => deleteTask(todo["id"])}>Delete</button>
                </div> 
            })} 
        </ul>


        <div>
          {errorMessage}
        </div>      
      </div>
  )  
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you mean `.filter(todo=>todo.id!=taskId)` The whole to do will never equal a integer

Answer (score 2):

You are equaling a `string` to a `number`, so it will never be `true`. Use this:

```
setTodos(oldTodos =>  oldTodos.filter(todo => todo.id !== taskID))
```